# Magento 2.3.1 MSI(Multi Stock Inventory) needs to disable

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

I have done the upgrade in one of the customer live projects from Magento 2.2.2 to 2.3.1 but not required MSI feature. Is it possible to disable all MSI modules in config.php? Once all the MSI modules disabled and it causes any issues?